# Did both anti-Nazi parties know about each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, inglourious-basterds, quentin-tarantino

In *Inglorious Basterds*, there are two parties of people planning on killing Hitler and everyone else at the theater. The first being Shoshanna and Marcel, who planned on burning the theater down, and the second being  Col. Aldo Raine and the Basterdsm who planned on blowing everything up.

My question is: **Did Marcel and Shoshanna know about the Basterds' operation and vice versa?** Because, unless I missed something, neither would've succeeded without the other. The Basterds would've only succeeded in killing Hitler and Goebbels because Marcel wouldn't have locked the doors and so as soon as the two leaders were shot, the rest of the Nazi leaders would've fled. Marcel and Shoshanna probably wouldn't have succeeded because by the time the theater burnt down, the Nazis would've just sent one of the guards guarding Hitler and Goebbels down to unlock the doors and everyone would've fled as well.

Please explain if I'm missing something.

Comment: One also needs to ask why Hitler was so casually guarded ?

Comment: @Rahul That could be a good question if you want to post that as a separate question.

Comment: @F1Krazy: This is a bigggggggggg plot hole as Hitler was always guarded by a unit of 8-12 dedicated SS bodyguard known as [Führerbegleitkommando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-Begleitkommando_des_F%C3%BChrers)

Comment: @Rahul I noticed that as well lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there is no depiction of collaborative effort to annihilate Nazi leadership because Shoshana and Marcel never met anyone from Lt. Aldo Raine's team at any point in the movie.

Both plans were independent efforts. Though Lt. Raine's was much more detailed and thorough as compared to Shoshana's plan.

I say so because Raine's main objective was to kill everyone in the higher leadership of the Nazi Party who was present in the theater that night. His plan also included causing explosions to kill officials in the audience but that would be a plus. So he deployed tactical teams with explosives and weapons.

But Shoshana's plan was to cause as much damage as possible by setting the theater on fire and hoping that everyone inside was engulfed into its flames. She didn't directly target Hitler or Goebbels.